# Rspec controller test: undefined method 'orders_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Writing some controller tests, using `render_views` to check some partial rendering....

```
describe PromoCodeController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'show" do
... a bunch of tests

it "renders 'used' partial when promo code has already been used" do
  @promo_code = create(:promo_code)
  @user.stub(:promo_used?).and_return(true)
  get 'show', :slug => @promo_code.slug
  expect(response).to render_template(:partial => 'promo_code/_used')
end
```

which loads in the `_used` partial

```
<article>
  <p><%= @promo.description.html_safe %></p>
  <p>Sorry, it appears this promo code has already been used. Please try again or contact us directly.</p>
  <%= link_to "View Order", orders_path(@order), class: "box-button-black", data: { bypass: true } %>
</article>
```

but breaks with:

```
undefined method `orders_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd4069d06e8>:0x007fd401e3e518>
```

Any ideas on how to either
(a) ignore the Rails link, it's irrelevant to the test
(b) include something in the test to recognize that link
(c) stub it (last resort i think)

Everything I've tried so far doesn't get past the error.

EDIT:

`orders_path` was wrong, it should be `order_path`. After changing that I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:controller=>"order", :action=>"show", :id=>nil}
```

So the partial is looking for `@order`. I tried setting it with `controller.instance_variable_set(:@order, create(:order))`, but in the partial it comes back as `nil`.

A quick test by adding`<% @order = Order.last %>` in the view partial passes green. How to pass the var `@order` into the `_used` partial is now the question.

Comment: Did you add orders resource to your config/routes.rb?

Comment: Should it be order_path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I needed to change it to `order_path`, `orders_path` was wrong. Doh.

Than I needed to stub some methods to get around the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:controller=>"order", :action=>"show", :id=>nil}
```

Ultimately, stubbing the method `assign_promo_to_users_order` which assigns a complete order to the current_user did the trick:

```
it "renders 'used' partial when promo code has already been used" do
  @promo_code = create(:promo_code)
  @user.stub(:promo_used?).and_return(true)
  User.any_instance.stub(:assign_promo_to_users_order).and_return(create(:order, :complete))
  get 'show', :slug => @promo_code.slug
  expect(response).to render_template(:partial => 'promo_code/_used')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the spec's type.

I believe that the action controller URL helpers are included into the spec type.

Try:

```
describe SomeController, type: :controller do
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually setting the spec type you can set it based off file location

```
# spec_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end 

describe 'GET SHOW' do
  run this in a before block 
  before do 
    controller.instance_variable_set(:@order, create(:order)) 
  end 

  it "renders 'used' partial when promo code has already been used" do
    promo_code = create(:promo_code)
    @user.stub(:promo_used?).and_return(true)
    # check if @order variable is assigned in the controller 
    expect(assigns(:order).to eq order 
    get 'show', slug: promo_code.slug
    expect(response).to render_template(:partial => 'promo_code/_used')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks David... I still get `ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:controller=>"order", :action=>"show", :id=>nil}`. Still not getting @order over to the partial

Comment: Ryan can you copy and paste your show method in PromoCodesController  ?